# How do I use the batch ultility of Graphics Magick?

Tags: batch-processing, graphicsmagick

I'm sure that my mistake is plain simple. I'm fair new to this application and after seeing the online help for batch I copy and paste the code for jpg conversion (to tiff) and it didn't work. The error it gives is: "gm: unrecognized command 'for'. Use help ... " and I don't get it, isn't batch utily this for (the use of shell script)? If someone can copy a simple script for this porpouse it will help me a lot. Thanks

PD: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2013/02/integrate-java-and-graphicsmagick.html) gives a deeper explanation of how GM batch mode works. Try out the examples there should help you to understand the examples used in the online help.